# Am I correct to read the line which this judge is saying?

Tags: word-meaning

Could someone kind help me understand **[what she is trying to say.](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/06/17/482484836/94-year-old-former-auschwitz-guard-found-guilty-of-complicity-in-170-000-murders)**

From 3 from the bottom

> When she handed down the verdict, Judge Anke Grudda said, "**This trial is the very least that society can do to give ... at least a semblance of justice,** even 70 years after and even with a 94-year-old defendant," according to AFP. She added:

Is she "regretting" or such kind that because of the age of the defendant, she was only able to give him the minimum punishment???

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The judge is saying that, while she is doing the best she can to achieve justice, she can't really even come close, partly because the man went free for 70 years after his crimes, and partly because his crimes were so heinous (he worked at Auschwitz) that no punishment could ever make up for them.